# How to make CherryPy HTTPS work with WSGI

Tags: python, ssl, https, wsgi, cherrypy

How does one setup WSGI with HTTPS ontop of Cherrypy? Right now I have (python2):

```
[imports]

server = wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', port), application)
ssladapter = ssl_pyopenssl.pyOpenSSLAdapter('ta_io.crt', 'private.key')
server.ssl_adapter = ssladapter
try:
    server.start()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    server.stop()
```

This doesn't appearently work. Firefox dies with:

```
SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG
```

Chrome keels over with:

```
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

After much puzzlement I saw that the page loads when I request it with `http://[my page]:443`.

From this I conclude that I do not enable HTTPS correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of CherryPy? Stackoverflow has some "that version is broken with SSL" Q and A pages ;-)

Comment: Ok, it was 3.5. I installed the new version from PIP and it works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: You'd better use some external web-server (e.g. `nginx`) to manage protocol-level connection encryption (i.e. SSL/TLS)